# Get number as name with INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, mysql

I've got this 3 tables:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for computers
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `computers`;
CREATE TABLE `computers`  (
  `id_pc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `case` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mobo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cpu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gpu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `psu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ram` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hdd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pc`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_case`(`case`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_mobo`(`mobo`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_cpu`(`cpu`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_gpu`(`gpu`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_psu`(`psu`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_ram`(`ram`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_ssd`(`ssd`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_hdd`(`hdd`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_case` FOREIGN KEY (`case`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cpu` FOREIGN KEY (`cpu`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gpu` FOREIGN KEY (`gpu`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_hdd` FOREIGN KEY (`hdd`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mobo` FOREIGN KEY (`mobo`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_psu` FOREIGN KEY (`psu`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ram` FOREIGN KEY (`ram`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ssd` FOREIGN KEY (`ssd`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`id_inventario`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for hardware_types
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hardware_types`;
CREATE TABLE `hardware_types`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `id`(`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `id_2`(`id`, `type_name`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 21 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for inventory
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory`;
CREATE TABLE `inventory`  (
  `id_inventario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `serial_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_inventario`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `fk_tipo`(`tipo`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tipo` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`) REFERENCES `hardware_types` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

On my c# program I need to get a DataGridView with the contents of 'computers' table, but some fields are foreign keys and the data is on 'inventory' table, how can I build a query to return the name based on the id on each field?

Example:

On computer table I have a a computer with CPU id 1 and GPU id 2, how can I return every field but instead the id I get the name?

I already tried to do somethings using INNER JOIN, but without success.

An example I've tried that always returns empty:

```
SELECT c.*, i.nome AS item_name
FROM
computers AS c
INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON i.id_inventario = c.caixa AND i.id_inventario = c.mobo AND i.id_inventario = c.cpu AND i.id_inventario = c.gpu AND i.id_inventario = c.psu AND i.id_inventario = c.ram AND i.id_inventario = c.ssd AND i.id_inventario = c.hdd
```

Data on computers table:

```
id_pc   nome        case    mobo    cpu gpu psu ram ssd hdd
1       Teste213    1       2       1   1   1   2   2   2
```

Data on inventory table:

```
id_inventario   nome    tipo    modelo      serial_number
1               Teste   0       teste       123
2               Teste2  1       1testesa    1234
```

I need to get the column "nome" when getting all rows on the computers column, like:

```
id_pc   nome        case    mobo    cpu     gpu     psu     ram     ssd     hdd
1       Teste213    Teste   Teste2  Teste   Teste   Teste   Teste2  Teste2  Teste2
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't, and I have done this already on other projects, but not with this many fields and I don't know, here's an example I've made: 
`SELECT c.*, i.nome AS item_name
FROM
computers AS c
INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON i.id_inventario = c.caixa AND i.id_inventario = c.mobo AND i.id_inventario = c.cpu AND i.id_inventario = c.gpu AND i.id_inventario = c.psu AND i.id_inventario = c.ram AND i.id_inventario = c.ssd AND i.id_inventario = c.hdd`

It always return empty, and I don't know why...

Comment: You're doing an inner join between `c` and `i` and saying that the `id_inventario` on the `i` table has to equal 8 different things. Why do you expect it to return anything?

Comment: Now I added OR, and it returns, but only returns once the item_name, and I need to return the name on each column, I've never done one like this, only some basic examples...

Comment: Please update your question with your corrected query, a sample of data in each table, and the expected result of your query given that sample.

Comment: @AdamV added the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple JOINs, 1 for each column:

```
SELECT c.id_pc, c.nome, i1.nome AS 'case', i2.nome AS 'mobo'
FROM computers AS c
INNER JOIN inventory AS i1
ON i1.id_inventario = c.case
INNER JOIN inventory AS i2
ON i2.id_inventario = c.mobo
INNER JOIN ...
```

[Check out a SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9033e2/5)

If you prefer, instead of using `i1`, `i2`, you could name the different `inventory` JOINS to distinguish them more easily (`AS 'iCaixa', AS 'iMobo'`, etc).

Comment: I got the query working directly on mysql, but when I try to use the query on C# it crashes: `Unknown column 'c.id_pc' in 'field list'`

I get this error on: `MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Got it working, I was diving by lines and I didn't give a space at the end, it was putting all together... http://prntscr.com/jmk89y

Thanks for your help